# How to capture the Null values(custname) and respective CustID in separate file and the rest of the CustID's in other file

Tags: datastage

| CustID | CustNAme |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Ally |
| 20 | null |
| 30 | null |
| 40 | Liza |
| 50 | null |
| 60 | Mark |

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an artificial key (e.g. line number) on each file.  Then have the source of CustID as the stream input to a Lookup stage, and the source of CustName as the reference input of the Lookup stage, where the lookup key is LineNumber.  Set the Lookup Failed rule to suit your own needs.
One way to generate line numbers is a Column Generator stage operating in sequential mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Transformer Stage with two output links. Use the output link constraints to check on null values to split the stream.

As constraint, just write `IsNull(DSLink2.CustNAme)` or `IsNotNull(DSLink2.CustNAme)` respectively.

***Note:** You can also write `!IsNull(col)` or `Not(IsNull(col))` for `IsNotNull(col)`*